# Python BeautifulSoup extracting text from result

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the text from contents but when i try beautiful soup functions on the result variable it results in errors.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

webpage = 'http://www.dictionary.com/browse/coypu'
r = requests.get(webpage)
page_text = r.text

soup = bs(page_text, 'html.parser')

result = soup.find_all('meta', attrs={'name':'description'})  

print (result.get['contents'])
```

I am trying to get the result to read;

"Coypu definition, a large, South American, aquatic rodent, Myocastor (or Myopotamus) coypus, yielding the fur nutria. See more."

Comment: `result.get('contents')` maybe?

Comment: You have an issue in result.get, should to use result[0].get("content"), You are using "contents".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`soup.find_all()` returns a list. Since in your case, it returns only one element in the list, you can do:

```
>>> type(result)
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
>>> type(result[0])
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
>>> result[0].get('content')
Coypu definition, a large, South American, aquatic rodent, Myocastor (or Myopotamus) coypus, yielding the fur nutria. See more.
```

Answer (score 1):

When you only want the first or a single tag use *find*, find_all returns a *list/resultSet*:

```
result = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name':'description'})["contents"]
```

You can also use a *css selector* with *select_one*:

```
result = soup.select_one('meta[name=description]')["contents"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you need not to use findall as only by using find you can get desired output'

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

webpage = 'http://www.dictionary.com/browse/coypu'
r = requests.get(webpage)
page_text = r.text

soup = bs(page_text, 'html.parser')

result = soup.find('meta', {'name':'description'})

print result.get('content')
```

it will print:

```
Coypu definition, a large, South American, aquatic rodent, Myocastor (or Myopotamus) coypus, yielding the fur nutria. See more.
```

Comment: Was *find* not already covered in my answer that I added a day before yours?

Comment: I missed that,sorry for it as I looked into question and his code and wrote mine